# flutter android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

The current Dart SDK version is 2.15.1.

Because flutter_projects requires SDK version >=2.17.6 <3.0.0, version solving failed.

but the dart version is 2.19.0

Comment: can you include `flutter --version` output and your project pubspec,yaml

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you can just update pubspec.yaml file. Write this instead.

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.15.1 <3.0.0"
```

Or upgrade your flutter version by running:

```
flutter upgrade
```